# How to convert map into array to firestore? flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a users id I want to add it to firestore, like this

```
['GEcuHm3ICpWlEzfq1Z2tAjI2LII3', 'GEcuHm3ICpWlEzfq1Z2tAjI2LII3' ...]
```

I tried multiple ways but it didn't work

```
List membersListUid = [];

Future createGroup() async{
    GroupRoomModel newGroup = GroupRoomModel(
        groupName: groupName.text,
        groupRoomId: uuid.v1(),
        owner: userModel.uid,
        membersList: controller.membersList,
        membersListUid: controller.membersListUid.cast() // <---
    );
}
...
```

```
Future createGroupFunc() async{
    GroupRoomModel newGroup = GroupRoomModel(
        groupName: groupName.text,
        groupRoomId: uuid.v1(),
        owner: userModel.uid,
        membersList: controller.membersList,
        membersListUid: controller.membersListUid.map((e)=> e).toList() //<---
    );
...
```

Maybe this helps to understand the code

```
//Controller class

Map<String, dynamic>? userMap;

  onSearch() async {
    await _fireStore
        .collection('users')
        .where("email", isEqualTo: searchedMembers.text)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      userMap = value.docs[0].data();
    });
    update();
  }

membersListUid.add({
        "uid": userMap!['uid']
      });
```

It's still gives me map within array.

Comment: Yes it is a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM:**

`membersListUid` is a List of Maps. That is why you get an array of Maps in your database.
You need to get the actual value of the `uid` from each Map by using the `uid` key to get the value from the map.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Update this line:

```dart
membersListUid: controller.membersListUid.map((e)=> e).toList()
```

to this below:

```dart
controller.membersListUid.map((e)=> (e as Map<String, dynamic>)['uid']).toList()
```